# How to find Encoding for 1251 codepage

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I need to create System.Encoding for 1251 codepage.

On my russian Windows I use

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default
```

I am afraid this will produce different results depending on Windows

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencoding.aspx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Correct, you will get different results on different machines if you use `Encoding.Default`.

If you want a specific codepage, you can use [Encoding.GetEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx):

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
```

Comment: Yeap, I should have just RTFM. Another option is specifying codepage by name instead of number as you did. In my case that would be windows-1251

Answer (score 19):

For .NET Core you also need to reference the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package and then use Encoding.RegisterProvider:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Answer (score 4):

The .NET Framework/.NET Core supports a large number of character encodings and code pages. To retrieve an encoding that is present in the .NET Framework/.NET Core pass the EncodingProvider object to the Encoding.RegisterProvider method to make the encodings supplied by the EncodingProvider object available to the common language runtime. [Microsoft Document Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider.instance?view=netcore-3.1)

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is a [`GetEncoding()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-7.0) overload taking an `int` (codepage) parameter:

```
Encoding encodingByCodePage = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
```

Also for .NET Core and .NET 5+ you need to call the [`Encoding.RegisterProvider()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.registerprovider?view=net-7.0) method to make character encodings available on a platform. If you don't call it, you will probably get a `System.NotSupportedException` saying

> 'No data is available for encoding 1251. For information on defining a
> custom encoding, see the documentation for the
> Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'