# C#, data from ms sql, Russian characters displays as ? when in windows was set English language for non Unicode application

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, winforms, encoding

In Base we have varchar for string meanings.
In our applications russian characters from database displays as '?'.
For connection we use OleDb.
How can we set encoding for all datas from Data Base. There o lot of tables.
CulturalInfo not working.
For WPF and WinForm applications.

Comment: You have to deal with encoding (not culture, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11293994/1997232)) and use an unicode font (it should contains Russian characters).

Comment: Also see those related topics: [varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16112982/1997232), [convert from .. to ..](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922199/1997232), [russian encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3967716/1997232), [extra](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14560223/1997232).

Comment: In single string it is easy to add spesial method.But what to do in case of DataSet?

Comment: Can you already display Russian `string` properly? Show how you doing it now (as well as how you obtain data from database) and point where is the problem. It's unclear how `DataSet` matters.

Comment: The problem is solving by changing OleDb to SQL provider